# Airpod Pro V2 case chirps / beeps when I pick it up

Tags: airpods

My Airpods Pro V2 case sometimes "chirps" (beeps) for ~15 seconds when I pick it up in the morning. It happens about once a week, and it wakes up my wife. It is like someone is using the "Find My" app to make the Airpods case emit noise, but there's no notification on my iPhone, or on any device in my "Family" group (Settings > Apple ID > Family).

**Updated to add:** This sound is **not** the "ding" it makes when I plug in the charging cable (or put it on the wireless charging pad). The "charging case sound" is just a single chime, maybe 2 seconds long. In contrast, this weird sound is more like the dinging of an alarm clock -- maybe 10-15 seconds long.  And, weirdest of all, it even makes this 10-second sound when I lift it, fully charged, off the charging pad. So I don't think it's a "low battery" sound.

How can I debug this? Thanks!

Comment: I have limited experience with these (they hurt when I used them) so, I’m doing this from memory… there should be  a setting to “enable charging sounds” or to that effect.  Is that enabled?  Also, I believe this chirp might be due to a low batter condition.  Try noting whether they are charged or not when they begin chirping.

Comment: Just reread my comment.  I think I would chirp too if I had  a low batter condition.  Especially cake batter.  Mmmm, cake,

Comment: @Allan - "Charging sounds" are enabled: They make a pleasant "ding" when I plug them in, or put them on a wireless charging pad. However, I think the troublesome chirps / beeps are unrelated to "charging sounds", since they occur even when they are sufficiently charged.

Comment: I know nothing about these devices, but 'chirp' is described in this article as the charging noise - https://www.techradar.com/how-to/airpods-pro-2s-case-is-too-noisy-for-me-heres-how-to-quieten-it

Comment: @Tetsujin - Thanks. That article assumes your phone is iOS 16 or up. Apple won't allow my phone to update to iOS 16 because it thinks my iPhone is too old (iPhone 6S). Luckily I have a Macbook on MacOS Ventura and I was able to turn off "Enable charging case sounds" by going to Settings > Bluetooth > Airpods Pro V2 > "i" (info) > Airpod Pro Settings... > Enable charging case sounds > "off". We'll see if that fixes it.

Comment: Wish you luck. btw, the SE 2020 is a good swap for the 6S, same size, still has a button & fits the same case, but needs a trim for the bigger camera.

Comment: I also asked Apple's forums, and they said to call Apple support: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/254602768

Comment: Update: Disabling "Charging case sounds" did not fix the problem. It still makes a 10-15sec beeping / chirping occasionally when I pick it up in the morning.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This happened to me. Somehow my AirPods got confused between my phone and my spouse’s phone and thought they didn’t belong to me. Symptoms included: AirPods chimed whenever I picked them up even though case sounds were turned off and they were fully charged; occasionally got the “not your AirPods” warning when connecting to them with my phone, AirPods showed up in FindMy but with a yellow warning icon.

I tried all kinds of things. What eventually fixed it was fully resetting the AirPods with [these instructions](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT209463) and then going through set up with my phone again.

1. Put your AirPods in their charging case, and close the lid.
2. Wait 30 seconds.
3. Open the lid of your charging case, and put your AirPods in your ears.
   Go to Settings > Bluetooth. Or go to Settings > [your AirPods].
   If your AirPods appear there as connected, tap the More Info button  next to your AirPods, tap Forget This Device, then tap again to confirm.
   If your AirPods don't appear there, continue to the next step.
4. Put your AirPods in their charging case, and keep the lid open.
5. Press and hold the setup button on the back of the case for about 15 seconds, until the status light on the front of the case flashes amber, then white.
6. Reconnect your AirPods: With your AirPods in their charging case and the lid open, place your AirPods close to your iPhone or iPad. Follow the steps on your device's screen.

Comment: In my case, it happened again a few days after resetting.

Answer (score 3):

Does it sound like any of these? AirPods Pro 2 have 'Find My' built-in and perhaps this is the 'moving with you' chime that I hear every time I get in my car (inside which I have stashed an AirTag.)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c0TVHPHRjXg

Comment: Thanks @Diggory. This is helpful. From the video, my Airpod Pro V2 case is making the "Moving with you" sound, described as: "This sound plays autonomously when an unknown Airtag has been moving with you over time." Find My is enabled for my Airpods Pro V2 (On my Mac with my Airpods connected, go to System Settings > left nav bar > scroll down to bottom > [my airpods name] > Find My network > it was on). So perhaps the problem is that the Airpods are not properly associated with me. I need to somehow designate them as "mine" so that they won't think they're being stolen when I pick them up :)

Comment: I think that perhaps the issue is not that they're not seen as "yours" by your phone - I think that your phone knows that they are yours, but rather that they don't know your wife's phone.

When Apple designed AirTags they didn't want them used as stalking / tracking devices, so they built-in these sounds so that if someone secreted one on you, or near you,  it would let you know.  Perhaps the AirPods are doing the same with your wife's phone.   Although it seems like this would happen a lot with couples if my theory was correct....

Comment: As a commenter above said, your best bet might be to call Apple Support and explain that they are making the 'moving with you' sound.  They might have seen this before.

Comment: So.... is the way to resolve this then pairing the airpods to the wife's phone one time in order to "introduce" it? Keeping it in her phone's bluetooth list, but turning it off for "automatically connect"? That does not seem ideal, but hopefully is a path forward.

Answer (score 2):

The same thing happened to me today, I bought new Airpods, and in the morning I picked them up and the case started ringing waking up my girlfriend. I believe it's indeed this function "Moving with you", as Apple says "This sound plays when an unknown AirTag/AirPods has been moving with you over time".

So basically my girlfriend's iPhone sees my "unknown" airpods and they start ringing. I guess a solution is to disable "charging case sounds" from AirPods settings, I don't want to pair them with her iPhone. Will see if it works.

It could also be this other function "separation alerts". (see [Get separation alerts if you leave your AirPods behind](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/airpods/devc1ce9b72b/web))
I don't know but it's bothering me.

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same problem. I managed to capture a video and Apple support told me this is “move with you” sound due to Airpod Pro 2 case’s Airtag-like feature. They told me this is independent of charging case sound option so it cannot be disabled. They said it must be a defective product and they can try to do a full reset if I send it back.

I was in a work retreat with C-levels for few days and my Airpod case was making a random noise during the meeting after not touching it for a while. I assume it’s because there were many Apple devices around and we move together to lunch/conference rooms/etc.

This is a fundamentally flawed design by Apple, which is disappointing.
They should either implement an option to disable it, or not implement at all. Typical Apple way, no way to customise as an end user. :(